# jQuery add item to object

Tags: jquery

rough day, cant even figure out how to add an item to an object.

```
var holder = {};
```

I have tried the following to add an item to object:

```
function AddToHolder(questionid, customerid) {
        $(holder).extend({
            questionid: questionid,
            customerid: customerid
        });
        console.log(holder);
    }
```

this returns empty

```
 function AddToHolder(questionid, customerid) {
        holder.questionid = questionid;
        holder.customerid = customerid;
        console.log(holder);
    }
```

this overrides the object, so its not adding, its overriding

Comment: Why not just use `holder. questionid = questionid;`?

Comment: I tried that, its not adding, its overwriting

Comment: @user979331 It will if you are sending repeat `questionid`.Either use a array or concat some kind of unique string with it perhaps?

Comment: are you wanting an array of objects with those 2 properties?

Comment: @user979331: Overwriting what?  Not adding to what?  Where exactly do you want this new value *added*?  Do you want an array of `questionid`s?  What do you want your object to look like?  P.S. You are using `extend()` incorrectly.  It should be `$.extend(holder, {...});`.

Comment: The normal usage is `$.extend(holder, {questionid: ...}`, what you're trying to do is use a selector which holds nothing

Comment: @blgt: You *can* do `$(holder)`.  It will make a jQuery object that contains the object.  It's not a good idea though and serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery Extend works like this

```
function AddToHolder(origin, questionid, customerid) {
    $.extend(origin, {
        questionid: questionid,
        customerid: customerid
    });
    console.log(origin);
}
```

To be aware to not override, just check if property exists

```
function AddToHolder(questionid, customerid) {
    if(!holder.questionid){
         //assign
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`$(holder).extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/) is not doing exactly what you want it to. What you are doing is extending the jQuery object containing `holder`. For example:

```
var $holder = $(holder).extend({
    testing: 2
});

console.log($holder.testing); // Shows 2
```

If you want to extend the plain object without it being wrapped in jQuery, you can use [$.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/):

```
// Option 1 - Modify the original object
$.extend(holder, { test: 2 });

// Option 2 - Create a new object without modifying the original
var newHolder = $.extend({}, holder, { test: 2 });
```